# Storing sparse matrices in SQL for quick retrieval and deserealization

Tags: arrays, postgresql, storage, sparse-matrix, data-retrieval

Interested in storing a sparse vector  (technically the sparse array is a key value pair dictionary but let’s just say that the values are an array for simplicity) and retrieving it from Postgres efficiently. The table schema would be:

- id
- sparse_array

Few options being considered:

- store array using ARRAY type on Postgres
- Store as a JSON
- Encrypt/decrypt the array using some sort of two-way encryption scheme - JWT concept?
- Convert into character (comma, for example) separated string and serialize/deserialize using C

Are there industry practice/good ways of doing this? Big tech companies can deliver images super quickly to users, how is that made possible/how does storage/retrieval work?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the post, thanks for the catch. But basically, what's industry practice for doing this? What are effective serialization/deserialization options for matrix market format files?

Comment: Delivering images is done by a CDN, content delivery network. How you store your data, depends mostly on your technology and your requirements. For flexibility I would most likely go for JSON